# Reflectively save domain class instances in Grails

Tags: json, grails, reflection, polymorphism

The problem is as follows: I want to handle a POST request with JSON body. The body consists of an array of JSON Objects, without further nesting, i.e. simple HashMaps. All of these objects represent JSON-serialized domain classes from an Android Application, which will have their counterpart in my Grails app. I am thinking of parsing the JSON body, iterating through every element and saving each node as its corresponding domain class instance.
a) How should I save the instance? I am quite new to Grails/Groovy so please excuse any huge mistakes. Code so far is

```
public static Object JSONArray2Instances(String json, Class type) {

    def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def result = slurper.parseText(json)
    //we only want to parse JSON Arrays
    if (!(result instanceof JSONArray))
        return null
    result.each {
        def instance = it.asType(type)


        // now I need to save to domain class!

    }
}
```

b) where do I place the corresponding code? Currently it is in /grails-app/src/groovy. Where do the tests go? (Since it is not a 'real' Grails component)

c) Is an intermediate command object more appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should go in to the controller which is handling the request. Please take a look at 
[gson-grails plugin](https://github.com/robfletcher/grails-gson) which has examples of how to serialize and deserialze objects and map them to domain objects. Please take a look at the grails basics where they talk about the conventions used in the grails application and the layout. There are good examples at [grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#creatingAnApplication) site. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you allthenutsandbolts but this is not what I am looking for. In fact this is not a back to the basics scenario. I would use a controller if I knew which domain class I would bind to, but the problem is I do NOT know it beforehand. I have an array of JSON objects and each one can correspond to ANY domain class, which all derive from the same superclass. So, I want to bind using "reflection" if this is the correct way to describe it.

Comment: You don't have to have controller for each domain class. Since you are going to accept array of JSON objects they can be handled in one controller and you can delegate this to the service class which will process this JSON objects. You do know some how that which JSON object maps to which domain class,  you just have to iterate over your data and then persist it. I don't see where the issue is

Comment: Ok that makes sense, so to recap: I handle the JSON body in a controller which corresponds to an "abstract" domain class,delegate to a Service which iterates over each object and then persists each one to the database. However, I cannot yet understand from the grails-gson documentation how a POST request which contains JSON in the style of [{..},{...},...] fits in. I mean, it would be great if such an array would get automatically bound to multiple domain class instances, but if it doesn't happen,how would I get it just converted to a JSON array so I would later iterate over it in the Service?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem as follows, based on help provided by the comment from allthenutsandbolts. : (Grails-Gson plugin was not needed)

Let **N2696AdminAction** be the name of a Domain Class

in my controller:

```
class N2696AdminActionController extends RestfulController{

    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']


    def JSONHandlerService


    N2696AdminActionController() {
        super(N2696AdminAction)
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    def save(){
        if (request!=null)
        JSONHandlerService.instancesfromJSON(request.JSON)
    }
}
```

then I delegate persisting to my service as follows

> class JSONHandlerService {
>
> ```
> def instancesfromJSON(Object request){
>
>     //we only want to parse JSON Arrays
>     if (!(request instanceof JSONArray))
>     return null
>     request.each {
>
>         def domainClass = Class.forName("${it.type}",
> ```
>
> true, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())
>
> ```
>         def newDomainObject = domainClass.newInstance(it)
>         newDomainObject.save(failOnError:true, flush:true, insert: true)
>
>
>     }
> ```
>
> }
>   }

***type*** is a Json attribute which holds the full (package inclusive) name for my class. This way, I can save to multiple Domain Classes with the same POST request.